# Как остановить setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5

Нужно чтобы после создания ***100-го*** элемента `setInterval` выключался. Можно ли это сделать без создания дополнительных переменных, типа такого:

```
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  alert( "work" );
}, 2000);
```

Уже все перепробовал, но никак не выходит.

Вот код:

```js
function foo() {
  var field = document.getElementById('field');
  var count = 1; //счетчик
  function addElem() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('block');
    div.innerHTML = count;
    field.appendChild(div);
    count += 1;
  }
  setInterval(addElem, 20);
}
```

```css
#field {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(16, 165, 115);
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="foo()">Create</button>
<div id="field"></div>
```

Comment: Чтобы сбросить таймер, установленный через `setInterval`, надо знать `id` этого таймера. Для этого его надо где-то запомнить. Без переменной это сделать затруднительно.

Comment: Почему вы не попытались погуглить, прочитать в документации, в учебнике посмотреть?

Comment: @Yaant, но если постараться...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, я же не сказал, "невозможно". Так-то сразу пришла мысль про что-нибудь типа `localStorage.setItem('timer', setInterval(...))`, но озвучивать я ее постеснялся. :)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. Нужна переменная.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var i = 0
  
  function tick() {
    if (++i === 10) clearInterval(t)
    document.body.textContent = i
  }
  
  var t = setInterval(tick, 1000)
  tick()
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет ничего плохого в объявлении дополнительных переменных. Но если очень хочется, то можно совсем без объявлений, на замыканиях - правда через setTimeout, а не setInterval, т.к. чтобы остановить setInterval вам нужно знать его id.

```
function interval(count, timeout, callback) {
    if (count === 0) return;
    callback()
    setTimeout(() => interval(count - 1, timeout, callback), timeout)
}
interval(10, 100, () => console.log('your code'))
```

Ваш пример без переменной для setInterval

```
function foo(){
    var field = document.getElementById('field');
    var count = 1; //счетчик
    function addElem(){
        var div = document.createElement('div'); 
        div.classList.add('block');
        div.innerHTML=count;
        field.appendChild(div);
        count += 1; 
        if (count < 100) {
            setTimeout(addElem, 20);
        }
    }
    addElem()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно остановить таймер через какое-то время, а не при достижении определённого значения, то можно обойтись без переменной. Но **количество вызовов функции таймером НЕ гарантируется**.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var i = 0
  
  function tick() {
    document.body.textContent = ++i
  }
  
  setTimeout(clearTimeout, 10500, setInterval(tick, 1000))
  tick()
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях лучше всего на какое-то время отвлечься от конкретной задачи, которую вы решаете. И если вам не хватает функции, которая вырубает интервал через N итераций, то напишите её!

Обойтись без переменных, конечно, не получится, но без контекста создания dom-элементов всё станет гораздо проще!

```
function nInterval(func, delay, limit) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (limit < 1) {
            return clearInterval(interval);
        }
        func();
        --limit;
    }, delay);

    return interval;
}

var i = 0;
var id = nInterval(function() {console.log(i++)}, 1000, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вместо `setInterval` использовать `setTimeout` и вызвать его N раз, через цикл:

```js
for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log( 'Вызов номер ' + (i + 1) );
  }, i * 500 );
}
```

Обращаю внимание на указанный таймаут, `i * 500` - сам цикл выполняется практически сразу. Но на каждом круге создается новый таймер, больше чем у предыдущего. И через указанные промежутки запускается функция.

Если сильно хочется использовать `var` вместо `let`, можно на каждом круге ловить текущее значение i через функцию и тутже её вызывать:

```js
for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
  (function(i){ 
    setTimeout( function(){
      console.log( 'Вызов номер ' + (i + 1) );
    }, i * 500 );
  })(i);
}
```